# How to open a killed React Native app from background service on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing a React Native app which uses Agora.io for making calls. Target platforms are Android and iOS. Costs and time are limited, so native (Swift + Java/Kotlin) way is not acceptable. As a trade-off, I am using react-native-callkeep to get as close to native call UI as possible.

Basically, the flow is:

1. User A presses "Call" button, then he/she is taken to Call Screen, and push notification is sent to User B (callee).
2. User B receives the push.

   - 2.1. User B's app is in foreground. Native call UI is shown using react-native-callkeep, user presses "Answer", then he is redirected to Call Screen. This scenario works fine.
   - 2.2. User B's app is in background. The push is handled by a background service (I know it may be called different on iOS/Android, but hope you get what I mean). Then, on Android I use the following code to bring app to foreground:

```java
// In a native module:

@ReactMethod
public void launchMainActivity(String uri) {
    String packageName = reactContext.getPackageName();
    Intent launchIntent = reactContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();

    try {
        Class<?> activityClass = Class.forName(className);
        Intent activityIntent;
        if (uri != null) {
            activityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri), reactContext, activityClass);
        } else {
            activityIntent = new Intent(reactContext, activityClass);
        }
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        reactContext.startActivity(activityIntent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

```js
MyModule.launchMainActivity(`https://myapp.com/CallScreen?parameter=${value}`); // Link is simplified
```

This opens the app and tells react-navigation what screen I want to open and what params I want to pass to it. This works fine on Android.

Now I want the same on iOS. I was not able to find any example of how to do the same on iOS. So I tried to use deep links, but no success. I have added this to AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
  restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
  return [RNCallKeep application:application
           continueUserActivity:userActivity
             restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

and to Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
 <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
   <string>myapp</string>
  </array>
 </dict>
</array>
```

This is how I use it:

```js
Linking.openURL(`myapp://CallScreen?parameter=${value}`); // Link is simplified
```

And it says that it can not handle this link. But, if I just type the link in the browser, it suggests to open it in my app (and opens it, I get redirected to Call Screen).

So, finally, the question: how can I open my app on iOS from background service, if it is in background/killed? A way similar to how it is done on Android is highly preferred over linking.

BTW, this is how background service is registered (firebase is used):

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async message => {
  // Here we go
});
```

P.S.:

1. Background messaging itself works fine on iOS/Android.
2. react-native-callkeep works on iOS/Android.
3. Call flow works fine when app is in foreground on iOS/Android.
4. I have configured react-navigation for linking (and linking itself works on both iOS/Android).

Comment: You can't bring an app to the foreground in iOS without user interaction. You can display a push notification and if the user taps on it then your app will be launched. The better solution is to use CallKit which integrates your app with the native calling experience.

Comment: did you find any solution for your answer ?

Comment: @AmirDoreh AFAIK it is not possible on iOS.

Comment: so how did you manage to develop your app?:)  @ololoepepe